# Is there a simple way to create several TextFields with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I am attempting to create about a dozen TextFields and was wondering if there is a quick and easy way to do this.

```
  tfTime1 = new TextField();
  tfActivity1 = new TextField();
  tfTime2 = new TextField();
  tfActivity2 = new TextField();
  tfTime3 = new TextField();
  tfActivity3 = new TextField();
  tfTime4 = new TextField();
  tfActivity4 = new TextField();
  tfTime5 = new TextField();
  tfActivity5 = new TextField();
  tfTime6 = new TextField();
  tfActivity6 = new TextField();
```

I feel like there's a more efficient way of doing this that I am not aware of

Comment: nothing specific to javafx: do what you always do if you want to create multiple similar objects ...

Answer (score 4):

You could use a simple `for` loop to add new `TextField`s to a `List`:

```
List<TextField> timeTextFields = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    timeTextFields.add(new TextField("Time #" + i));
}
```